# Pandas and datetime coercion. Can't convert whole column to Timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timestamp, python-datetime

So, I have an issue. Pandas keeps telling me that

> 'datetime.date' is coerced to a datetime.
>   In the future pandas will not coerce, and a TypeError will be raised. To >retain the current behavior, convert the 'datetime.date' to a datetime with >'pd.Timestamp'.
>   I'd like to get rid of this warning
>   So until now I had a dataframe with some data, I was doing some filtration and manipulation. At some point I have a column with dates in string format. I don't care about timzeones etc. It's all about day accuracy. I'm getting a warning mentioned above, when I convert the strings to datetime, like below:

```py
df['Some_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Some_date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

So I tried to do something like that:

```py
df['Some_date'] = pd.Timestamp(df['Some_date'])
```

But it fails as `pd.Timestamp` doesn't accept Series as an argument.
I'm looking for a quickest way to convert those strings to Timestamp.

=====================================

**EDIT**

I'm so sorry, for confusion. I'm getting my error at another place. It happens when I try to filtrate my data like this:
 `df = df[(df['Some_date'] > firstday)]`
Where `firstday` is being calculated basing on datetime. Like here:

```py
import datetime

def get_dates_filter():
    lastday = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    firstday = lastday.replace(day=1)
    return firstday, lastday
```

So probably the issue is comparing two different types of date representation

Answer (score 1):

In pandas python dates are still poor supported, the best is working with datetimes with no times.

---

If there are python dates you can convert to strings before `to_datetime`:

```
df['Some_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Some_date'].astype(str))
```

If need remove times from `datetimes` in column use:

```
df['Some_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Some_date'].astype(str)).dt.floor('d')
```

**Test**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=3).date
df = pd.DataFrame({'Some_date': rng})  
print (df)
    Some_date
0  2017-04-03
1  2017-04-04
2  2017-04-05

print (type(df.loc[0, 'Some_date']))
<class 'datetime.date'>

df['Some_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Some_date'].astype(str))
print (df)
   Some_date
0 2017-04-03
1 2017-04-04
2 2017-04-05

print (type(df.loc[0, 'Some_date']))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

print (df['Some_date'].dtype)
datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jezrael  However, it doesn't change a lot. Pandas still show that warning about coercion

Comment: @Kraxi - Can you add some sample data

Comment: @Kraxi - testing in sample data ans working perfect for me in panda 0.25, added sample data to answer.

Comment: You are completely right @jezrael. My mistake in identification where is the problem. I put and EDIT to the original question. It seems that comparing dates is the cause of the warning